# How to hide DIVs using a class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

```
var array1 = document.getElementsByClassName("div");
var array2 = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

    for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
    {
        $(array2[i]).show();
        $(array1[i]).hide();

        $(array2[i]).click(function(){
            $(array1[i]).slideToggle();
        });
    }
```

Why I got error:
Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0?

Comment: Post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo. Otherwise you're unlikely to get a good answer, since we can't see what's going wrong with what you've got.

Comment: Did you mean `getElementsByTagName`? Because `div` and `buttons` are standard tags in HTML. not class.

Comment: You're obviously using jQuery, why are you mixing?

Comment: What does `How to hide div not by name` actually mean? What do you want to do?

Comment: How does you markup look? Please post it here.

Comment: It's a variable scoping issue. While the mix of plain JS and jQuery is unusual, it will work once the scope is fixed.

Comment: To be precise, `$(array1[i]).slideToggle();` inside the click handler is causing the error as `array1` and `i` are 1. not in scope, 2. Not going to be desired element.

Comment: @Vega: They are in scope (judging from the given code), but `i` will be an index not in the array...

Comment: @FelixKling You are right, array1 is in scope, but the i is greater than index. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/et4ac/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var $buttons = $(".button").hide();

$(".div").show().bind("click", function(event) {
    var index = $divs.index(this);

    $buttons.eq(index).slideToggle();
});
```

OR:

```
var $buttons = $(".button").hide(),
    $divs = $(".div").show();

$.each($buttons, function(index) {
    var $button = $(this);
    $divs.eq(index).bind("click", function() {
        $button.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

OR

```
var $buttons = $(".button").hide(),
    $divs = $(".div").show();

$buttons.each(function(index) {
    var $button = $(this);
    $divs.eq(index).bind("click", function() {
        $button.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't mind upvoting this, as you've implemented my suggestion.

Comment: I believe you're using index() incorrectly, it should be $('.div').index($(this));

Comment: @KorvinSzanto From: http://api.jquery.com/index/: `If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.`

Comment: @AndreasAL: Exactly... what makes you think the `div`'s are all siblings? `$divs = $(".div")` and `$divs.index(this)` would be better. At least it does not make any assumptions of the structure.

Comment: @FelixKling you right again. Think there is no place for me here tonight... Im to tired to think strait!!

Comment: I like that I correct him, AndreasAL denies, @FelixKling steps in and corroborates, then AndreasAL gives in.